# Unable to run node-gdal on Alpine Linux: "__printf_chk: symbol not found"

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, gdal, alpine-linux

I'm trying to add Gitlab CI for my project using [node-gdal](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal) (Node.js bindings for [GDAL](https://www.gdal.org/)). CI configuration is based on Alpine Linux docker image due to performance reasons but I'm unable to get it working. Gitlab CI job fails while running Node.js script that requires `node-gdal` with the following error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: Error relocating /builds/project-0/node_modules/gdal/lib/binding/node-v64-linux-x64/gdal.node: __printf_chk: symbol not found
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/builds/project-0/node_modules/gdal/lib/gdal.js:12:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

Tried to install [glibc for Alpine](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/) but still with no luck.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: node:lts-alpine

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache bash ca-certificates wget
    - wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub
    - wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.29-r0/glibc-2.29-r0.apk
    - apk add glibc-2.29-r0.apk
  script:
    - yarn
    - node index.js
```

This is a [repo](https://gitlab.com/ezze/node-gdal-ci) reproducing the issue and this is a [link to failed job](https://gitlab.com/ezze/node-gdal-ci/-/jobs/167372634).

Is there any solution to use the library on Alpine?

Comment: Created [related issue](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal/issues/254) on Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36329133/506695) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527030/506695) related questions and answers, I was able to build `node-gdal` linking against shared GDAL library on Alpine with the following CI configuration ([link to passed job](https://gitlab.com/ezze/node-gdal-ci/-/jobs/167397317)):

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: node:lts-alpine

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache bash make gcc g++ python linux-headers udev --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main gdal gdal-dev
  script:
    - npm install gdal --build-from-source --shared_gdal
    - node index.js
```